# pickle a cython class containing __cinit__ : __setstate__ vs __reduce__?

Tags: python, cython, pickle

I'm working on making some cython objects pickeable and have a question about using `__setstate_` vs `__reduce__`. It seems that when you `pickle.loads()` an object with a `__setstate__` method and also a `__cinit__` method, the `__cinit__` DOES get called (unlike if it were an `__init__`). Is there a way to prevent this or pass a default argument or should I just use `__reduce__`?

Here's a toy problem to illustrate (code modified from this [blog](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2016/04/16/pickling-cython-classes/)).

in `test.pyx` I have three classes:

```
cdef class Person:
    cdef public str name
    cdef public int age

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        print('in Person.__init__')
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age 

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.name, self.age,)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        name, age = state
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

cdef class Person2:
    cdef public str name
    cdef public int age

    def __cinit__(self,name,age):
        print('in Person2.__cinit__')
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age 

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.name, self.age,)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        name, age = state
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

cdef class Person3:
    cdef public str name
    cdef public int age

    def __cinit__(self,name,age):
        print('in Person3.__cinit__')
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age 

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (newPerson3,(self.name, self.age))

def newPerson3(name,age):
    return Person3(name,age)
```

After building with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, pickling `Person` works as expected (because `__init__` does not get called):

```
import test 
import pickle 

p = test.Person('timmy',12)
p_l = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p))
```

Pickling `Person2` fails:

```
p2 = test.Person2('timmy',12)
p_l = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p2))
```

with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.pyx", line 25, in test.Person2.__cinit__
    print('in Person2.__cinit__')
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (0 given)
```

So `__cinit__` gets called....

The `__reduce__` method in `Person3` works as expected:

```
p3 = test.Person3('timmy',12)
p_l = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p3))
```

So is there a way to use `__setstate__` to pickle `Person2`?

In my actual problem, the classes are more complex and using `__setstate__` would be more straightforward, but maybe I have to use `__reduce__` here? I'm new to cython and custom pickling (and also don't know C well......), so may be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell: Use [`__getnewargs_ex__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs_ex__) or [`__getnewargs__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) to provide the needed arguments to `__cinit__`-method.

How does it work? When a Python object is created, this is a two step process:

- First, `__new__` is used to create an uninitialized object
- In second step, `__init__` is used to initialize the object created in the first step

`pickle` uses a slightly different algorithm:

- `__new__` is used to create an uninitialized object
- `__setstate__` (and no longer `__init__`) is used to initialize the object created in the first step.

That makes sense: `__init__` has nothing to do with the "current" state of the object. We don't know parameters for `__init__` and even if `__init__` would have no parameters, it could possible do unnecessary work.

Where comes the `__cinit__` into the play? When `__cinit__` is defined, Cython defines automatically a `__new__`-method (that is the reason it is impossible to define a `__new__`-method manually in a `cdef`-calls), which calls the provided `__cinit__`-method before returning. In `Person2`-example, this functions looks as follows:

```
static PyObject *__pyx_tp_new_4test_Person2(PyTypeObject *t, PyObject *a, PyObject *k) {
  struct __pyx_obj_4test_Person2 *p;
  PyObject *o;
  if (likely((t->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_IS_ABSTRACT) == 0)) {
    o = (*t->tp_alloc)(t, 0);
  } else {
    o = (PyObject *) PyBaseObject_Type.tp_new(t, __pyx_empty_tuple, 0);
  }
  if (unlikely(!o)) return 0;
  p = ((struct __pyx_obj_4test_Person2 *)o);
  p->name = ((PyObject*)Py_None); Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  if (unlikely(__pyx_pw_4test_7Person2_1__cinit__(o, a, k) < 0)) goto bad;
  return o;
  bad:
  Py_DECREF(o); o = 0;
  return NULL;
}
```

`if (unlikely(__pyx_pw_4test_7Person2_1__cinit__(o, a, k) < 0)) goto bad;` is the line where `__cinit__` is called.

With the above it becomes clear, why `__cinit__` gets called by pickle, and we cannot prevent that, as `__new__` must be called anyway.

`pickle` however provides futher hooks to get the needed information for `__cinit__`-method to the `__new__`-method: [`__getnewargs_ex__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs_ex__) and [`__getnewargs__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__).

Your `Person2` class could look as follows:

```py
%%cython
cdef class Person2:
    cdef public str name
    cdef public int age
    
    def __cinit__(self, name, age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __getnewargs_ex__(self):
        return (self.name, self.age),{}

    def __getstate__(self):
        return ()
    
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        pass
```

and now

```py
p2 = test.Person2('timmy',12)
p_l = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p2))
```

does succeed!

This is a toy example, which doesn't make much sense and thus:

- `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` are here just dummies, because all needed information is provided by `__cinit__`, in general this is not the case.
- in this example `__cinit__` doesn't make much sense, it would make more sense to have `__init__` instead.

---

Often one uses `__cinit__` rather then `__init__` for cdef-classes. However in general it is not 100% correct and when pickling is involved, it is important to decide what is happening in `__cinit__` and what is happening in `__init__`.

The other extrem, i.e. to put the whole initialization code into  the `__init__`-method, is tempting to solve issues with pickling. However, the combination `__new__`+`__init__` isn't atomic, it is possible that `__new__` is called and then the object is used before (or instead like `pickling` does,) `__init__`-method was invoked, which might lead to NULL-pointer-dereferencing and other crashes.

One also must be aware, that while `__cinit__` is executed exactly once (when `__new__` is executed), `__init__` can be executed multiple times (for example `__new__` can be overwritten a subclass in such a way that it always returns the same singleton), that means:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef char *a
    def __cinit__(self):
       a=<char*> malloc(1)
```

is ok, while the same code in `__init__`:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef char *a
    def __init__(self):
       a=<char*> malloc(1)
```

is a possible memory-leak, as `a` could be an initialized pointer and not `NULL`, which is guaranteed only for `__cinit__`.

Answer (score 2):

[The purpose of `__cinit__` is that it **always** gets run.](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init)

> Your `__cinit__()` method is guaranteed to be called exactly once.

In contrast `__init__` can be uncalled (for example in your case, or in inherited classes) or called multiple times.

The value of `__cinit__` always being called is that many classes with C types must be setup in a certain way or they're automatically invalid - for example they might expect to pointer to be initialized to some memory that the class holds. (This is the sort of invalid that leads to an automatic crash to desktop, rather than "Python" invalid which should just lead to Python exceptions).

Since your toy example only holds Python objects you'd probably be better just using `__init__` - there's no reason it *must* be initialized. You can have both `__init__` and `__cinit__` if you want, to separate the parts that must happen from the parts that just happen in a normal initialization.

If you do chose to use `__cinit__` but want to call it from a variety of contexts with different numbers of arguments the documentation recommends

> you may find it useful to give the `__cinit__()` method `*` and `**` arguments so that it can accept and ignore extra arguments.

---

In summary, use `__cinit__` to do the initialization that has to happen for your program not to crash. Accept that it'll be called from `__setstate__` (since you don't want your program to crash after you use `__setstate__`, right?). Combine it with `__init__` to do the initialization that should should generally happen but isn't required and that may sometimes be overridden. Use default arguments or `*` and `**` arguments to make `__cinit__` flexible enough for your needs.