# Why can't a Cython object with the __cinit__ method be pickled?

Tags: python-3.x, cython, pickle

As outliend in this documentation (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#controlling-pickling) Cython objects with the `__cinit__` method can't be pickled. But why?

This is a question out of interest - so that I can understand what makes certain Cython objects pickleable and so that others who are also confused by this fact may understand why it is so.

(Also please note that I am quite new to Cython, so I am not sure whether `__cinit__` is present on all Cython objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be pickled. Cython can't *automatically* generate the pickle/unpickle method.

The process of unpickling essentially does:

```
def unpickle(some_dict):
    obj = Cls.__new__(Cls)
    obj.attr = some_dict['attr']
    ...
```

(hugely simplified for illustrative purposes).

`__cinit__` means that `Cls.__new__(Cls)` won't/is unlikely to work - you likely have to pass it a strict list of arguments, or that `__cinit__` initializes it to some custom state that Cython doesn't know about.

You can manually make the class pickle-able as described in [the pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances). It's just that Cython won't attempt to do it for you.

---

**Edit** (for clarification):

The first thing to understand is that (unlike `__init__`), `__cinit__` is absolutely guaranteed to be called when an object is created. Therefore it isn't possible to unpickle an object without `__cinit__` being called.

The simplest case to understand is when `__cinit__` takes some arguments. In this case Cython doesn't know what those arguments should be or how they relate to the state of the object when pickled. Just as a trivial example:

```
cdef class C:
   cdef int a
   def __cinit__(self, a_equals_two):
      if a_equals_two:
          self.a = 2
      else:
          self.a = 3
```

When Cython pickles an object it stores the state of `C.a`. But working out what `a_equals_two` should be from that isn't trivial.

For the case where `__cinit__` doesn't take any arguments it's less obvious why Cython can't pickle it. The logic is mainly "the user has decided that initialization is complex and they want to handle it themselves, therefore Cython shouldn't try to interfere". It isn't a case that Cython could *never* do the right thing - it's just about not second-guessing user intent.

You should use `__cinit__` mainly for cases where you want to ensure initialization *always* happens and happens exactly once per instance - for example initializing a wrapped C object. If you're not concerned about that then use `__init__` and the problem goes away. See [In Cython class, what's the difference of using __init__ and __cinit__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827538/in-cython-class-whats-the-difference-of-using-init-and-cinit) for more detail.

Another related question: [pickle a cython class containing __cinit__ : __setstate__ vs __reduce__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069471/pickle-a-cython-class-containing-cinit-setstate-vs-reduce)

Comment: Okay, thank you. In light of this new information, my confusion is more so as to why Cython can't automatically generate the pickle/unpickle method. That is: what doesn't pickle have access to that should inhibit it from generating the pickle/unpickle methods automatically?

Comment: I've added a bit more clarification. I suspect you're not going to be entirely happy with the answer because in a lot of cases Cython *could probably* do something but is choosing not to. But hopefully it explains the logic a little more.